# Why is my UV Map in separate parts?

Tags: edit-mode, workflow, uv-image-editor

I have a simple shape that I want to add a texture to. But when I unwrap it, it shows in separate pieces rather than one whole square like the tutorial shows.

Incidentally, when I first came to ask this question, I had a different problem — my lines where all shooting out of bounds and going all over the place. I found the answer to that (Smart UV Project) but that's when it gave me the separate shapes. It's probably easier to just recreate the shape, but I am curious to know what I did wrong to end up like this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how *Smart UV Project* looks like.

I never checked the donut tutorial, so I don't know what's the base mesh you worked with, but when you start with blenders base mesh **Torus** object, it gives you nicely unwrapped UVmap into square already.

---

Basically to get more control over Unwrapping, you have to

- **Mark Seams** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to let blender know where to split a net
  (the edges marked by red color in screen, just select two edge loops with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> select)

[image]

- select all faces and Unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> > **Reset**
- select only one face and Unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> > **Follow Active Quads**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. I must of done something along the way to distort it so it no longer lays as one large grid. I tried what you did and it didn't seem to make a difference. If I select part of my Torus, the UV Map shows the area I selected all over the place. So its impossible to try and paint around it shape.

Comment: Distortion is not a problem and from your screen it seems like even grid. If you want, upload your blend just with donut object via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question, so we can check it.

Comment: Here you go. I actually am sending what the mesh originally looked like before I "fixed" it using the Smart UV Project.  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=7oaBaPxL" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7oaBaPxL/)

Comment: Works for me with your file as well https://imgur.com/hI7ByBk Note - in your UVmap are pinned vertices, they aren't the issue, but would be better to UnPin (Alt+P) them.(BTW I asked you to place code into your question (left down - edit), not into comments. Thank you to keep this site organised.)

Comment: nice! Thank you vklidu. Appreciate your time.

Comment: If answer helped you solve the issue consider mark answer as accepted so others can see it as solved from main list. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour